# Role of exotic animals in the culture of Solomon's age

Tags: 2-chronicles, plants-and-animals

In 2 Chronicles 9:21, exotic animals are listed among luxury goods:

> The king had a fleet of trading ships of Tarshish manned by the sailors sent by Hiram. Once every three years the ships returned, loaded with gold, silver, ivory, apes, and peacocks.

(depending on the translations, different kind of animals are reported: monkeys, apes, baboons, peacocks, ...).

These animals are not commonly referred to (or no referred to at all) in other episodes talking about opulence items (for examples when describing building of adornment elements for monuments or religious articles).

What was the general people's behavior of the King's age toward exotic animals? Did they have any particular religious meaning? Or they were just status symbols, like gold and silver? What these animals were used for?

Comment: Solomon imported them because he was wealthy enough to do so; ie, he did it because he could, and, it was a status symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of story-telling, the apes and peacocks are mentioned to demonstrate the exotic nature of the the king's trade ventures with Sheba, whose Queen had visited and established mutual relations in the first part of the chapter. While there is no particular religious significance to apes and peacocks per se, there is indeed a spiritual significance to Solomon's owning them. Also there is an important difference between the Chronicler's treatment of this story compared with that of the author of I Kings.

It is fairly easy to understand the Chronicler's reason for reporting about these animals. Borrowing from the earlier report in 1 Kings, he mentions them as evidence of Solomon's unequalled power and glory during Israel's Golden Age. Immediately following the verse cited in the OP, we read:

> 22 Thus King Solomon surpassed all the kings of the earth in riches
> and wisdom. 23 All the kings of the earth sought audience with
> Solomon, to hear the wisdom God had put into his heart. 24 They all
> brought their tribute...

The author clearly wants us to know of Solomon's great glory, which ultimately came from God.

However if we turn to the parallel description of Solomon's wealth in 1 Kings 10, we find an additional emphasis. In Kings, this chapter emphasizes Solomon's glory, but the next chapter exposes the fact that his love for his many wives led to his spiritual fall and the ultimate division of his kingdom. (Solomon's love for his many wives and his consequent idolatry are not directly mentioned in Chronicles.) Thus, the mention of apes and peacocks in Kings demonstrates not only the king's glory, but also the fact that Solomon put large sums of money into the trappings of power - of these trappings being his opulent harem, which eventually led to his downfall. In that sense, the additional spiritual/religious meaning of the apes and peacocks would be that they were part of a dangerous pattern in Solomon's character.

**Conclusion**: if one reads Chronicles, the religious significance of the exotic animals is to demonstrate the glory of Solomon's reign. If one reads the Books of Kings, they serve to show both his glory and his vanity, which lead to his downfall.